# top align lrbox

Tags: vertical-alignment, boxes, tufte

Is there a way to top align two `lrbox`? I try to mimic the captions of tufte-latex. On the left, what I want, on the right, what I got so far.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}

\geometry{
    a4paper,
    left=24.8mm,
    top=27.4mm,
    headsep=2\baselineskip,
    textwidth=107mm,
    marginparsep=8.2mm,
    marginparwidth=49.4mm,
    textheight=49\baselineskip,
    headheight=\baselineskip,
    twoside,
    asymmetric,
    showframe,
}

\usepackage{caption}

\newsavebox{\mycaptionbox}
\newsavebox{\myfigurebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\myfigurebox}%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\hbox{}%
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}%
    \end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}%

\begin{lrbox}{\mycaptionbox}%
    \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}\hbox{}%
        \captionof{figure}{\kant[1]}%
    \end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}%

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    \hbox{%
        \usebox{\myfigurebox}%
        \hspace{\marginparsep}%
        \smash{\usebox{\mycaptionbox}}%
    }%
\end{minipage}%
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: an lrbox is always single line so doesn't have an alignment option, but inside it you want `\begin{minipage}[t]` to top align the minipages

Comment: Perfekt, thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you submit an answer, I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `lrbox` is always single line so doesn't have an alignment option, but inside it you want `\begin{minipage}[t]` to top align the minipages